# Changing Background Color in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the background color of a table when the mouse hovers it. How do I fix it?

I get this error: "Unexpected token ERROR" in Google Chrome

```
    echo '<table id="a1" onmouseover="document.getElementById(\'a1\').backgroundColor = #CCCCCC;">
    <td align="center"></td></table>';
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this could just be done in css... using #a1:hover{background-color:#CCC;}

Comment: You may want to consider doing this via CSS or jQuery. Echoing out a whole bunch of js events won't be very efficient or easy to maintain. If you have questions about those choices just ask!

Comment: @mrtsherman, jQuery is also Javascript and even if he has to do this with JS, jQuery is overkill.

Comment: @omeid - I am aware that jQuery is javascript =). He can write this in a single line of jQuery. Or he could write a lot of javascript or a lot of redundant javascript. Why not use tools that make your development fast and easy? Of course the whole thing is moot since the real answer is CSS.

Comment: @mrtsherman: your fast development shouldn't cost resources.

Comment: and sure thing css is the way to go for this situation, as I mentioned *if he has to*...

Comment: @omeid - jQuery is 19kb gzipped and can be retrieved from a Google CDN  with a year long cache expiration date. Most people should already have a cached version because it is so widely used now. I don't consider it too heavy, but perhaps you do.

Comment: @OmeidHerat let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2465/discussion-between-mrtsherman-and-omeid-herat)

Answer (score 2):

#CCCCCC should be a string, \'#CCCCCC\'

Answer (score 1):

```
function changeBackground(color) {
   document.getElementById('a1').backgroundColor = color;
}

<table id="a1" onmouseover="changeBackground('red');">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
echo '<table id="a1" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor=\'#ccc\'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor=\'#000\'">
<td align="center"></td></table>';
```

Because,

1. `backgroundColor` is a property of `style` property of the `HTMLElement`.
2. `#CCCCCC` should be in quotes

An ideally you should use the powerful `this` keyword in scenarios like this.

Comment: Thanks! Now how do I change the background color to nothing? Like - no background color at all? I tried putting nothing in the color string - but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to pull this off, it will run faster and look nicer (you won't get any screwy edge cases).

```
#a1 {
    background-color: #FFF;
}

#a1:hover {
    background-color: #CCC;
}
```